# Axios Post Request does not function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-props

I'm new to react and Axios and I want to send a set of data to an API using Axios in React, this is the data format in API:

```
{
    "company_name": "Karno",
    "title": "Devops Engineer",
    "internal_code": 856789,
    "department": 1,
    "location": 2,
    "tags": [10, 11],
    "benefits": "At Snapp, we like spending ...",
    "description": "About Snapp..." 
    "requirements": "Mandatory QualificationsStrong Linux administration skills..."
}
```

and this is my code which is going to send these data when a button is pressed (these data are saved in the props and shown on this confirmation form page) to the API, but my post request doesn't seem to work, I don't receive any response from the server and I don't see any POST request in my server log

```
const headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Token bba27954e46823f1f82ff2c89d19f5802e46fd3f'
}

export class Confirmation extends Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
    company_name: '',
    internal_code:'',
    department:'',
    location:'',
    tags:[],
    benefits:'',
    description:'',
    requirements:''
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const job = {
      title:this.values.Title,
      company_name:this.values.Company,
      internal_code:this.values.InternalCode,
      department:this.values.Department.id,
      location:this.values.Location.id,
      tags:this.values.Tags.map(tag=>tag.id).join(', '),
      benefits:this.values.Benefits,
      description:this.values.Detailss,
      requirements:this.values.requirements
    }
    axios.post('/api/jobs/job-creation/',{headers:headers}, job)
    .then(res=> {
      console.log(res)
      console.log(res.data)
    })
  }

continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };

  back = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
  };

render () {
    const {
      values: {
        Title, Benefits,
        Company, InternalCode, Detailss, Department,Tags, Salary,requirements,Location,newTags
      }
    } = this.props
 return (
    <form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div className='container'>
 <div className='content'>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col xs='6' sm='4' className='TextContent'>
                <Row className='TextInside'> Salary: {Salary} </Row>
                <Row>  Location: {Location.label}</Row>
                <Row>  New Tags: {newTags.join(', ')} </Row> 
              </Col>
              <Col xs='6' sm='4' className='TextContent'>
                <Row>   Company: {Company}</Row>
              // info in the {} are shown on page and need to be sent to api
                <Row>   Internal Code: {InternalCode}</Row> 
                <Row>   Pre Tags: {Tags.map(tag=>tag.label).join(", ")}</Row>
                <Row>   Department: {Department.label}</Row>  
              </Col>
              <Col xs='6' sm='4' className='TextContent'>
                <Row>   Job Title: {Title}</Row>
                <Row>   Benefits: {Benefits}</Row>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
       <div className='Detailss' style={{width:'1000px'}}>
         {Detailss}
       </div> 
<div className='req'>
       {requirements}
      </div>


      //buttons
      <div className='buttons-container' style={{position:'relative',bottom:'20px'}}>
       <button onClick={this.back} className='previous'>قبلی</button> 
       <button type='submit' onClick={this.continue} className='next'>ادامه</button>
     </div>

     </Container>
     </Container>
    </div>
    </form>
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you get errors in the network tab of your browser?

Comment: @HMR no, I have a few get requests that work properly and another post request that works properly too but this post request doesnt even come up in logs

Comment: Check the network tab and console logs in browser, it could be blocked by CORS or some other security policy.

Comment: @Kotofenum CORS are unlikely because in the question OP is posting to `/api/jobs/job-creation/`

Comment: @Kotofenum no my server is local and I dont have any network errors

Comment: have you checked that handleSubmit runs at least until axios function call?

Comment: Also, try to add .catch callback to axios.post chain and log the error that may occur

Comment: @Kotofenum added a catch : .catch(error => {
      console.error(error.response);  
    }) no errors in the console

Comment: @Kotofenum added a console.log(this.state.title) after the job array but prints nothing

Comment: I don't see the state object being used or set in your class, you just reference props directly. So I guess you should log job object instead.

Comment: You could also try to fire handleSubmit method somewhere else, for example in componentDidMount() to check whether the problem is in the handleSubmit itself or the way you call it.

Comment: Btw you should specify type="button" at
<button onClick={this.back} className='previous'>قبلی</button> 
or its type will also be considered as 'submit' inside of <form/>

Comment: @Kotofenum handleSubmit doesnt even log this.values.Title  which is supposed to be there from from the props. could it be because its not in onClick function in the button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213094/discussion-between-kotofenum-and-dorian).

Comment: You are not referencing props correctly: `this.values.Title` is not defined anywhere. `this.props.values.Title` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onClick listener on submit button triggers redirect before the onSubmit handler of form is fired. Remove onClick listener and move this.continue() to .then callback of the post request.

Also, remove 'e' parameter from continue method and e.preventDefault, and change this.values to this.props.values in job object.